# "Cannot find symbol" because .class not written correctly?

Tags: java, eclipse, forex

I'm a Forex-trader and recently started programming my own studies for the 'MotiveWave'-Platform (which is using java).
I'm trying to add an extra MA ("Moving Average", a line basically) to an existing MotiveWave Study, but keep getting 'Cannot find Symbol'-errors when building.

All the MW-example-studies from the MW-SDK-guide compile and run without issues (http://www.motivewave.com/support/sdk.htm). But when I add a few lines of code to the 'SampleMACross.java' file to have an extra MA-line drawn, it errors out on me. I have studies the MotiveWave SDK-guide thoroughly (http://www.motivewave.com/sdk/MotiveWave_SDK_Programming_Guide.pdf), but failed to come up with an answer.

This is (part of) the existing code:
(the complete code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/ACjMHY0i)

```
@Override
  public void initialize(Defaults defaults)
  {
    // User Settings        
    SettingsDescriptor sd=new SettingsDescriptor();
       setSettingsDescriptor(sd);


    SettingTab tab=new SettingTab("General");
    sd.addTab(tab);


    SettingGroup ma1=new SettingGroup("Fast MA");
    tab.addGroup(ma1);
    ma1.addRow(new InputDescriptor(Inputs.INPUT, "Fast Input", Enums.BarInput.CLOSE));
    ma1.addRow(new MAMethodDescriptor(Inputs.METHOD, "Fast Method", Enums.MAMethod.EMA));
    ma1.addRow(new IntegerDescriptor(Inputs.PERIOD, "Fast Period", 10, 1, 9999, 1));
```

And I add this:

```
    SettingGroup ma3=new SettingGroup("T89");
    tab.addGroup(ma3);
    ma3.addRow(new InputDescriptor(Inputs.INPUT3, "T89 Input", Enums.BarInput.CLOSE));
    ma3.addRow(new MAMethodDescriptor(Inputs.METHOD3, "T89 Method", Enums.MAMethod.EMA));
    ma3.addRow(new IntegerDescriptor(Inputs.PERIOD3, "T89 Period", 89, 1, 9999, 1));
```

And keep getting the 'Cannot find symbol'-errors for the lines containing Inputs.INPUT3 and Inputs.METHOD3 and Inputs.PERIOD3.

```
error: cannot find symbol
ma3.addRow(new InputDescriptor(Inputs.INPUT3, "T89 Input", Enums.BarInput.CLOSE));
                                     ^
symbol:   variable INPUT3
location: interface Inputs
```

First I thought I needed to declare these (new) variables somewhere in my code, but I cannot see the existing one (Inputs.INPUT, Inputs.METHOD and Inputs.PERIOD) being declared.
Then I thought this had something to do with these new variables not being written to my .class file by the Eclipse IDE, so I dug deeper on that issue, but to no avail.

Comment: It just means you're trying to use a field that doesn't exist: http://www.motivewave.com/sdk/javadoc/com/motivewave/platform/sdk/common/Inputs.html. See, there isn't any INPUT3 in the class Inputs.

Comment: Indeed ! That seems to be  the problem. I had no idea the class Inputs could only hold 2 'Inputs' and it had not yet crossed my mind to check there. Thanks !